# Control frame rate of video player in Vision System toolbox?

Tags: matlab, video, matlab-cvst

How can I control the playback rate of a video player in the Vision System toolbox in Matlab? Specifically, I want to slow video down. For instance, here is the simple example of how to load and display a movie [from the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader-class.html#examples):

```
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('viplanedeparture.mp4');
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;
while ~isDone(videoFReader)
  videoFrame = step(videoFReader);
  step(videoPlayer, videoFrame);
end
release(videoPlayer);
release(videoFReader);
```

I searched the User's Guide for how to change the frame rate in a simple way in such examples, but found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're displaying images as fast as they can be retrieved and displayed with your current code. If you want a particular framerate I would use a [`timer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) that calls your update methods based upon the frame rate that you want. Here is a brief example that should be pretty robust.

```
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('viplanedeparture.mp4');
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;

framerate = 10; % in frames/second

t = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
          'Period', 1 / framerate, ...
          'TimerFcn', @(tmr,evnt)timerfcn(tmr, videoFReader, videoPlayer), ...
          'ErrorFcn', @(tmr,evnt)cleanup(tmr, videoFReader, videoPlayer));

show(videoPlayer);
start(t)

function timerfcn(tmr, reader, player)
    % While we have more to read, read and display it.
    if ~isDone(reader) && isOpen(player)
        step(player, step(reader));
    else
        cleanup(tmr, reader, player)
    end
end

function cleanup(tmr, reader, player)
    % Callback to ensure proper cleanup of objects
    if isvalid(tmr) && strcmpi(tmr.Running, 'on')
        stop(tmr);
        delete(tmr)
    end

    release(player);
    release(reader);
end
```

Thanks to [horchler's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947438/control-frame-rate-of-video-player-in-vision-system-toolbox-matlab/35947541?noredirect=1#comment59553033_35947541) for improving the robustness of the solution.

The alternative is to place a `pause(1/framerate)` statement at the bottom of your `while` loop, but that won't take into account any time required to actually do the loading/displaying so the frame rate isn't going to be guaranteed to be very consistent.

## Additional Thoughts

The [comments made below by @neuronet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947438/control-frame-rate-of-video-player-in-vision-system-toolbox/35947541?noredirect=1#comment59576582_35947541) got me thinking about why this may not be a feature of either `VideoFileReader` or `VideoPlayer`.

### `VideoFileReader`

As @neuronet states, if the frame rate is specified within the video file that is being read using `VideoFileReader`, couldn't that be used automatically?

The answer is, yes if *could* be used but there is good reason to *not* use it. Since new frames are fetched with `VideoFileReader.step()` it woud have to be implemented as some sort of a rate limiter on `step()`.

In this particular case, the video is being used for display purposes; however, that is not always the case. A lot of times, you may want to load a video frame by frame to do some analysis (tracking an object, etc.). Now imagine for a second that the frame rate of my video file is set to 1 frame per second (fps). And let's say that I want to load this video into MATLAB, track people in the frame, and report back to the user how many people passed through the field of view during the course of the video.

If `VideoFileReader.step()` was written so that it returned images only at the frame rate specified in the file, this means that the *fastest* I could do my processing would be at one frame per second. If this were the case, the end user would just watch the video themselves and we would be out of a job!

Another important consideration is that if you actually want to *process* the video frame *before* displaying it to the VideoPlayer object, you need to somehow account for that processing time (which obviously the `VideoFileReader` has no clue about).

### `VideoPlayer`

The other option would be to have a `FrameRate` property for the `VideoPlayer` object itself.

While this too *could* be done, the way that it is currently implemented it is not possible. Currently to display a new frame, you have to explicitly call the `VideoPlayer.step()` method. It runs into the same situation as the `VideoFileReader`. It would have to be implemented as a rate limiter on the `step()` method.

One possible way that The Mathworks could make this work would be to have an alternative to using `step()` to update the image. For example, a `NextImageFcn` callback or something. Then `VideoPlayer` could internally setup a timer based on a specified frame rate and execute the callback when necessary (similar to our timer callback).

The other alternative could be to have `VideoPlayer` accept a `VideoFileReader` object as an input. It could then use this object to get information about the video (frame rate, etc.) and display the images at the appropriate speed.

The main issue here though, is that this serves a very small group of users. This is because the primary goal of MATLAB (and the computer vision toolbox) isn't to be a video playback system, but rather it is intended to do *analysis* on videos and the `VideoPlayer` object is intended to streamline the display of the results.

Maybe this functionality will be implemented in the future, but for now those are my thoughts on why it doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry for for introducing a typo while fixing others – stupid autocorrect. I just fixed another minor typo.

Comment: @horchler Not a problem. Thanks for the sharp eye.

Comment: To further improve this excellent answer, you could add `&& isOpen(videoPlayer)` to the `if` statement in `timerfcn` (you'll need to call `show(videoPlayer);` before or display the first frame). This would run `cleanup` if the user closes the window. `onCleanup` could be leveraged as well. Also, `timer` objects have global scope and are not being deleted so it would be good to add `delete(tmr);` to `cleanup`.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for the pointers. Did I place the `show(videoPlayer)` as you were expecting?

Comment: Yes, that will work nicely (and does in my testing).

Comment: @horchler I would test it but don't have the toolbox on my current machine. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Working on it, getting a few errors right now. E.g., `Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer: Undefined function or variable 'videoFReader'.` I'm working on sending things to the timer function.

Comment: @neuronet I assumed that you would already have `videoFReader` defined (based on your post). I have updated my post to be a complete example (including initialization of these variables)

Comment: Yep those are the changes I made, needed to send those objects to the timer fcns. Works now. So weird this isn't just a property to be set in the player, or a property of its step function.

Comment: "You're displaying images as fast as they can be retrieved and displayed with your current code." Is this really true? Or perhaps is it set by the properties of the loaded video? And if what you said is true, isn't that horrible default behavior for their program? This is literally the first example they have in their documentation for the toolbox! I have to say again, it is hard to believe that there isn't some simple property 'Oh just change 'displayRate' in 'videopPlayer' dummy, and it will display how you want! I guess the question is why would they not have this be a trivial thing?

Comment: @neuronet I have updated the post with some of my thoughts on it.

Comment: @Suever that's *really* helpful stuff there. Indeed, I am using it for image processing, not as a display tool, so everything you say is right on. Might be cool to make a video display tool that is meant to do *no* processing, but just have a few bells and whistles for displaying video data (e.g., change display rate, replay button, etc)...Not that it wouold ever replace a dedicated player, but something just to do a quick cursory glance at my data. I guess I'll get working on it. :) .But your explanation seems to hit the mark.

Comment: @neuronet well there is always 'implay' which has some of that.